# Regular Expression (first character matching a-z)

Tags: regex

I have this regex: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/`

What I want to add to above is:

- first character can be only `a-zA-Z`

How I could make this regular expression?

Comment: In which language? What should the *rest* of the regular expression match? Your current regular expression will match any string containing at least one character that isn't alphanumeric or an underscore or a hyphen: is that what you intended?

Comment: this will be used for username of website, first character must be chose from a-zA-Z and user can use a-zA-Z, 0-9, _ and -

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$
```

Explanation:

```
^                Start of line/string.
[a-zA-Z]         Character is in a-z or A-Z.
[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]  Alphanumeric or `.` or `,` or `$` or `;`.
+                One or more of the previous token (change to * for zero or more).
$                End of line/string.
```

Comment: This is quite different to the regular expression in the question (the `^` is inside the `[]`, not before it).

Answer (score 20):

I think this would also work

```
^[a-zA-Z].*
```

If you wanted to test just the first character as being alphabetical and the rest of the string can be anything.